# A 100% width div still wider than should be

Tags: html, css

I just faced a problem, one of my divs is too wide. I wanted it to fit browser size. Here's what's written:

```
<div><ul>
    <li style="width: 20%"><a href="1.php">1</a></li>
    <li style="width: 20%"><a href="2.php">2</a></li>
    <li style="width: 20%"><a href="3.php">3</a></li>
    <li style="width: 20%"><a href="4.php">4</a></li>
    <li style="width: 20%"><a href="5.php">5</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Here's the css file content:

```
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}      
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-image: url(myimage.png);
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
ul a {
     background-image: url(ndvder.png);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: right;
     padding-right: 30px;
     padding-left: 30px;
     display: block;
     line-height: 80px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 22px;
     color: #331D1D;
 }
 ul a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
 }
```

I used some css generator. Here's the part I completely don't understand:
If my `<ul>` is set to cover 100% of available width, why is it wider? I got that annoying scrollbar. I don't think it's fault of those 20% `<li>` elements, because they sum up to 100% :D. Where did I commit a mistake?

Comment: Why the inline-styles, `<li style="width: 20%"><a href="1.php">1</a></li>`? You could just target it like so, `ul > li { width: 20%; }`. Less writing for you and just makes more sense. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list has default padding.

Add `padding:0` to your `<ul>` rules.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FjQ6r/)**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-image: url(myimage.png);
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding:0;
}
```